# Factoring using the Brahmagupta Identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, factoring

**Brahmagupta Identity.**

$$
\begin{align}
(a^2+nb^2 )(c^2+nd^2 ) &= (ac-nbd)^2+n(ad+bc)^2 \newline
&=(ac+nbd)^2+n(ad-bc)^2
\end{align}
$$

We can factor $N$ using the Brahamagupta Identity by writing $N$ as $p^2 + nq^2$ and $r^2 + ns^2$ in two different ways.

---

This question is about whether we can use the fact

$$
\begin{align}
p &= ac - nbd \newline
q &= ad + bc
\end{align}
$$

from one of the representations to find the other.

For e.g., say $N = 19\times 73 = 1387$.

We can write $N = 1387 = 37^2 + 18 \cdot 1^2$ taking $p = 37, q= 1$ and $n = 18$.

We take any arbitrary integer value for $a$, say $a = 1$ then

$$
\begin{align}
p &= ac - nbd = 1 \cdot c - 18 bd \newline
q &= ad + bc = 1 \cdot d - bc
\end{align}
$$

Therefore,

$$
\begin{align}
-c^2 + c p + 18 d^2 - 18 d q = 0 \newline
\implies -c^2 + 37c + 18 d^2 - 18 d = 0
\end{align}
$$

This can be solved using Legendre's method for two variable quadratic diophantine equations.

There are multiple solutions $(c,d)$:

$$
\begin{align}
c &= -332, &d &= -82  \newline
c &= -332, &d &= 83  \newline
c &= -260, &d &= -65  \newline
c &= -260, &d &= 66  \newline
c &= -108, &d &= -29  \newline 
c &= -108, &d &= 30  \newline 
c &= -8, &d &= -4  \newline 
c &= -8, &d &= 5  \newline 
c &= 0, &d &= 0  \newline 
c &= 0, &d &= 1  \newline 
c &= 37, &d &= 0  \newline 
c &= 37, &d &= 1  \newline 
c &= 45, &d &= -4  \newline 
c &= 45, &d &= 5  \newline 
c &= 145, &d &= -29  \newline 
c &= 145, &d &= 30  \newline 
c &= 297, &d &= -65  \newline 
c &= 297, &d &= 66  \newline 
c &= 369, &d &= -82  \newline 
c &= 369, &d &= 83
\end{align}
$$

$c=37, d=1$ gives $c^2 + 18d^2 = 1387$, only a trivial divisor.

Is there a way we can fix this approach so that we can get the non-trivial divisors.

---

I am aware of Brillhart's method of factoring. But that requires computing the two representations which is what this question is about.

Comment: If this would work without knowing another representation , we could efficiently find at least one nontrivial factor of a Fermat-number , say of $F_{33}$. Hard to imagine.